# Batch replacing everything after the last underscore character to the beginning of the file extension

Tags: batch-file, automation, registry, batch-processing, batch-rename

So I want to replace this:

```
Brand_Name_18.jpg
```

With this

```
Brand_Name_close-up.jpg
```

I tried

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=1-3*delims=_" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg ^| find /i /v "_0_"') do ren "%%i_%%j" "%%i_%%j_0_"
```

but had no success. I also played with the PowerShell and was able to replace some characters there, but not particularly what I want. The characters I wanted to add were appearing at the end of the file extension, which broke everything...

```
Dir | rename-item -newname  { $_.Name + "_close-up }
```

.

```
get-childitem -recurse | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "_","_close-up" }
```

I would also like to make the batch appear in the window when I right click, so I could apply it to a file that I need it to be applied on. So that has probably something to do with the registry, right?

**SOLUTION** thanks to T3RR0R

```
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Change Directory and Remove /R recursive switch as / if necessary.
For /R %%A in (Brand_Name_*.jpg) do (
    REN %%~nxA Brand_Name_close-up.jpg
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. If you're processing a large subset of files, you'll be best off modifying it to rename using a suitable naming convention that doesn't require input.

```
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Goto :Main

:ModString <string length> <string> <target substring> <prefix VarName> <Substring Length>
Set String=%2

For /L %%L in (%1,-1,1) do (
    Set Test=!String:~%%L,%5!
    If /I "!Test!"=="%3" (
        Set %4=!String:~0,%%L!
        Exit /B
    )
)
Set /P "prefix=%3 not found. Set prefix:"
Exit /B

:StrLen <resultVar> <string> 
(  
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (set^ tmp=%~2)

    If Defined tmp (
        Set "len=1"
        For %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) Do (
            If "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
                Set /a "len+=%%P"
                Set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
            )
        )
    ) else (
        Set "len=0"
    )
)
(
ENDLOCAL
Set "%~1=%len%"
exit /b
)

:Main
    Set /P "Searchfolder=< Drop & Drag or Enter Parent Folder:"
    IF Not Exist "!Searchfolder!" Goto :Main
    Set /P "Extension=Extension:"
    Set /P "SearchString=Enter String to Locate:"

For %%V in (Extension SearchString) do IF "!%%V!"=="" Goto :Main

For /R %%A in (*!SearchString!*.!Extension!) do (
    Call :StrLen substringLen "!SearchString!"
    Call :StrLen prefixLen "%%~nA"
    Call :ModString !prefixLen! %%~nA !SearchString! prefix !substringLen!
    Echo(Rename: %%~nxA
    Set /P "Newstring="
    REN %%~nxA !prefix!!SearchString!!Newstring!%%~xA
)

CHOICE /N /C ny /M "more N/Y?"
IF errorlevel 2 (
    Set Extension=
    Set Searchstring=
    Goto :main
)
exit
```

**Update**
With the only known in your usage being that the underscore is the last instance in the name / string that you wish to retain in the new filename, the function needs to be modified to find it's position in the string using a String Length function in order to Modify the string from that point using Substring Modification.

The StrLen function is the work of [Jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb)

I've modified the code to now take a bit more input, and be more flexible. You can now use it with other extensions and define the String to search for at runtime.

Comment: If Brand_Name_ is a stand in for another / multiple other strings, you can replace it with %~1 and call the batch with the actual string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution! Brand and Names are changing constantly as there are multiple products from different brands. So basically I need it to ignore the words before the underscores. How could I do that? And how would I remove the input? Sorry complete beginner in scripting...

Comment: Figured how to do no input, still not sure how to make it ignore the first two words though.

Comment: I only need to change 1 file per folder, the Brand and Name should stay the same only replace the last one, but currently it doesn't work with anything that doesn't have Brand and Name in it. Tried with %~1 but doesn't work, not sure if I am positioning that part correctly...

Comment: Do you have any ideas? @T3RR0R

Comment: Using the /R recursive tag, the updated code can be applied to all relevent files in the subfolders, by finding the last instance of the search string and replacing everything after it with the defined new string

Comment: Damn, that's some complicated code... Thank you for taking your time and writing it!

Comment: [fairly simple compared to something like this](https://pastebin.com/FFAXjYNS)

That said, the code I've offered for your use is overcomplicated - It's written so it can be used for a wider variety of situations, to make it usable by others with similar questions